# Deshabilitar boton Volver Atras del navegador o emitir pregunta al presionarlo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, navegador-web

Necesito ayuda para deshabilitar el boton Atras del navegador o por lo menos emitir una pregunta al presionarlo, del tipo "¿Desea permanecer en esta página?"

He probado con el siguiente codigo en el HTML pero este se ejecuta cuando cargo la pagina y no al intentar salir:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirec() {
conf=confirm ("¿Quieres abandonar este Sitio?. Pulsa Aceptar o Cancelar");
if (conf) {window.location="http://www.abcdef.com"}
}
window.onbeforeunload=new function(){setTimeout("redirec()", 2000)}
```

Gracias desde ya, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer la funcion `.onbeforeunload` debes poner una frase para que confirme el usuario.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "¿Quieres abandonar este Sitio?"; };
```